# Chrome extension development: change font color by clicking color button in popup.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I try to develop a simple Chrome extension that allows to change font color for dragged content, when I click a button in popup.html. I use document.execCommand, but I don`t know how to transfer the color value which I chose from colorbox. Please help me.

Here are my codes:

***1. manifest.json***

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "test",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "description": "test",

 "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["<all_urls>"],
    "js":         ["content.js"]
 }],

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.3.1.slim.js", "background.js"]
 },

 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
 ]
}
```

***2. popup.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="fontColorButton">Font Color</button>
    <input  id="colormap" type="color" value="#000000"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

***3. popup.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fontColorButton').click(function() {
     chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "forecolor"});
     });
  });
  $('#colormap').click(function() {
    colormap = document.querySelector("#colormap");
    color = colormap.select();
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "colormap", color});
    });
  });
});
```

***4. content.js***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  if (request.message == "forecolor") {
    TextMode(request.message, value);
  }
  else if (request.message[0] == "colormap") {
    console.log(request.message[0]);
    value = request.message[1];
   console.log(value);
  }
});

function TextMode(mode, value) {
  document.designMode = "on"; // designMode on for execCommand
  document.execCommand(mode, false, value);
  document.designMode = "off"; // designMode off for execCommand
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{message: "colormap", color}` is not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but rather an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

A traditional way of constructing it would be `{message: "colormap", color: color}` but what you used is an acceptable [literal shorthand in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

So you should not be accessing its components with array indexing like `[0]`. There is, in fact, no notion or "order" of those, `{a: "a", b: "b"}` and `{b: "b", a: "a"}` are the same, so which one is 0th?.

Here's how you can do it:

```
else if (request.message == "colormap") { // Accessing property "message" of the object "request"
  console.log(request.message);
  value = request.color; // Accessing property "color" of the object "request"
//value = request["color"]; // Alternative syntax
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, still the function does not work. I think your comment could be applied after solving this problem, which I describe below. // 
I think there is a problem where a color is not selected in popup.js. When I click the button "input type=color", then a colormap is open. In succession, however, when I click a color in a colormap, the chosen color is not reflected on the button, and the color code is not even shown. Do you have any idea for this?